# Identify this sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

While browsing old code I had written in freshman year of college, I found the following snippet marked as 'bubble sort'. (here n is the size of the array; eg. for an array of 10 elements n = 10).

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
            int temp  = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
```

Now, i can tell that this certainly isn't bubble sort, but maybe a very poor implementation of it. Fact is it **works** and I'm curious if this is an algorithm that already exists or if it is something that I came up on my own albeit it being very inefficient.

Comment: It's a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) with extra useless swaps

Comment: Your first sort implementation you learn at school. To teach you what is slow..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Bubble sort only uses one index since it compares adjacent pairs. That is not the case here.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't see how. The inner loop is from `1` to `n-j` (which would be `n-i` here), and the comparison is between `[i]` and `[i-1]`, not `[i]` and `[j]`. If what you mean is that there are two (nested) loops and a swap, then I've got news for you: a whole lot of sorting algorithms match that description.

Comment: well geuss iám wrong in this case and seriously need some caffaine to wake up @Nelfeal this indeed looks more like selection sort algorithm indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a poor implementation of selection sort. Take a reference implementation ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation)):

```
for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
    int iMin = j;
    for (i = j+1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[iMin]) {
            iMin = i;
        }
    }

    if (iMin != j) {
        swap(a[j], a[iMin]);
    }
}
```

Instead of finding the minimum in the unsorted part and placing it at the end of the sorted part with a swap, your snipper just swaps everytime it finds a "potential minimum", that is a value lesser than the one past the end of the sorted part. That's inefficient because swaps simply cost more than index assignment.